# How to call time dependent action on change of date fields in Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, time-dependent-workflow, process, process-automation

**Use case -**

1. Suppose on Opportunity we have a date field "Close Date".
2. Whenever this Close date field changes we want to send email to User one day after changing this field.

**Note** - Time source should be when Opportunity Closed date updated.

**Challenge with flow is -**

1. When we add condition "Is Changed" we CAN NOT select "When to Run the Flow for Updated Records" to "Only when a record is updated to meet the condition requirements". Refer screenshot 1
2. We won't get option to add "Scheduled Path" > if we do NOT select "Only when a record is updated to meet the condition requirements" which is disabled in this case. Refer screenshot 2

**Solutions tried**

1. Compare Current and Prior values in flow

Problem - Even if we compare Current and Prior values we won't get option to schedule action

2. Create a formula field to check if date is changed

Problem - We can not check if field value "Is Changed" in formula field, we also can not get prior value in formula field

**Screenshot 1**
[image: Disabled - When to Run the Flow for Updated Records]

.

**Screenshot 2**
[image: Add Scheduled Path missing]

Comment: “Only when a record is updated to meet the condition requirements” This option is selected when we want the trigger to run as change happens from not meeting the condition to meeting the condition above, so you dont need ischanged when that option is selcted

Comment: You might try a scheduled flow on the opportunity history object.  Get the opps where close date was edited yesterday, and then do the needful.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare ClosedDate is NULL FALSE for entry criteria & select first option (every time a record is updated & meets the conditon requirements)
And, create schedule paths base on ClosedDate field.

It works same as Time-base action Workflow Rules.